# Finding Ip from an ether adress

Tags: arp-spoofing

I am using cocoa packet analyser because I am suspecting some intrusion. I find one special packet corresponding to arp protocol with some special ether adress. How could I find the ip related to this (I am a newbie for all these stuffs, so maybe my answer will be quite evident from you)

Comment: Probably a better fit for StackOverflow with a security tag.

Comment: or rather, [su]. This seems to be a networking question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I am wrong, but try to use wireshark 
[image]

Also I think that this might be useful http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocolsip/f/convertipmacadd.htm